# list_filter to display only filtered records depending on user login in django

Tags: python, django

How to show different records in the right-side list_filter depending on logged in user ?

eg If superuser logs in the list filter can view all the branches of all the customers in the changelist_view of branch in the list_filter. But if a customer logs in he should be able to see only his branches in the list_filter in django

Answer (score 1):

The current development version of django has support for [custom list filters](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_filter). As far as i know it is almost impossible to do in Django 1.3. If you really need this feature now you should consider switching to the dev branch.